# Seeking reference or guidance for multi-module spring-webmvc app where a module will have its own web resources and controller

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, multi-module

Existing Spring-webmvc web app, can't make substantive changes to the existing source. Need to add a module that will include its own Thymeleaf templates, some javascript, and java controller and service objects.

I've not been successful in finding a good guide or example on how to have this module function as part of the whole application...without having to move files into the existing webapp war during packaging.

Any suggestions?
MTIA!!

Comment: You need to be more specific about your project, what you have tried and what problems you want to solve.

Comment: I've tried adding a maven module project and configuring the @ComponentScan in the main webapp's WebDispatcherServletConfiguration class to include my package. I've also tried adding spring-webmvc as a dependency in the module's pom. I was hoping there might be a good reference on how to add a module like this (html, js, and java components) to an existing project somewhere. I was also wondering if this can be done without having to move my thymeleaf templates and javascript into the main webapp's resources folder during packaging. Basically a plugin I suppose.